# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, windows, pandas, anaconda, jupyter

I am on Windows 10, using Anaconda (Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64). I have not been able to resolve this error even after reinstalling Anaconda. I don't believe adding conda to PATH could be causing this.

(base) D:\KZ\Projects\Custom Vision>conda --version
conda 4.5.11

```
    (base) D:\KZ\Projects\Custom Vision>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "D:\Users\KZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "D:\Users\KZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "D:\Users\KZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "D:\Users\KZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 7, in <module>
    import copy
  File "D:\KZ\Projects\Custom Vision\copy.py", line 13, in <module>
    df=pd.DataFrame()
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

(base) D:\KZ\Projects\Custom Vision>
```

Here is what is inside test.py

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["test"]=pd.Series[list("abcd")]
```

However if I python from terminal and import pandas, it works fine. It only causes this issue when I execute the script.

```
(base) C:\Users\KZ>python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
>>> exit ()
```

Comment: Are you missing `df["test"]=pd.Series[list("abcd")]` in your terminal test?  
That's the reason why it is an empty dataframe?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the concern here. It is that in terminal I can import pandas in a python environment but when I run my script it shows that error.

Comment: @paradoxlover Perhaps you are right, in my case the file that was causing the error was a file named "copy.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how I'm understanding it (correct me if I'm wrong) your test.py is a bit more complicate than the one you gave here. Especially concerning the 'impot copy' part that is shown on the execution log. If I'm right, you have an import copy after your import pandas as pd in your test.py file. 
I think, since copy is also a keyword used in pandas, maybe the name of your copy.py is messing something with pandas. Try to remove it just for the test to see if the error is still there.

Comment: That did the job! thank you the error was that I had my script named copy.py in the directory. I've renamed it.

Answer (score -2):

See by including () in pd.Series

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["test"]=pd.Series([list("abcd")])
```